# How to rerender component in useEffect Hook

Tags: reactjs, redux, use-effect

Ok so:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    
  }, [props.lang]);
```

What should I do inside useEffect to rerender component every time with props.lang change?

Comment: Can you provide the full source? How are `Explore` and `RenderExplore` related?

Comment: Explore just render RenderExplore

Comment: You don't have to do anything in `useEffect` to rerender a component. If `props.lang` change, then you can use it as this in the render and it will always reflect the current value.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Think of your useEffect as a mix of `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate`, and `componentWillUnmount`, as stated in the React documentation.

To behave like `componentDidMount`, you would need to set your `useEffect` like this:

```
  useEffect(() => console.log('mounted'), []);
```

The first argument is a callback that will be fired based on the second argument, which is an array of values. If any of the values in that second argument change, the callback function you defined inside your `useEffect` will be fired.

In the example I'm showing, however, I'm passing an empty array as my second argument, and that will never be changed, so the callback function will be called once when the component mounts.

That kind of summarizes `useEffect`. If instead of an empty value, you have an argument, like in your case:

```
 useEffect(() => {

  }, [props.lang]);
```

That means that every time `props.lang` changes, your callback function will be called. The `useEffect` will not rerender your component really, unless you're managing some state inside that callback function that could fire a re-render.

UPDATE:

If you want to fire a re-render, your render function needs to have a state that you are updating in your `useEffect`.

For example, in here, the render function starts by showing English as the default language and in my use effect I change that language after 3 seconds, so the render is re-rendered and starts showing "spanish".

```js
function App() {
  const [lang, setLang] = useState("english");

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setLang("spanish");
    }, 3000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Lang:</h1>
      <p>{lang}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Full code:

[image: Edit heuristic-rubin-pmdjk]

Comment: I understand the concept of second argument. I need a rerender component after props.lang change. How can I managing some state with callback function?

Comment: e.g How fire re-render?

Comment: @PiotrŻak Check my updated answer, see if that helps somehow.

Comment: Hey - I pass to RenderExplore props.lang. It's eng or pl, and it's change, when user call action.
I need a rerender whole component, because i have layer of animation, and after lang change it's need to rerender to work well

Comment: How can I mount and unmount component after second argument in useEffect change?

Comment: When we use useEffect(() => { }, []); its execute one Times, But  useEffect(() => { }, [state]) execute each time that state will change

Answer (score 9):

## Simplest way

Add a dummy state you can toggle to always initiate a re-render.

```
const [rerender, setRerender] = useState(false);

useEffect(()=>{

    ...
    setRerender(!rerender);
}, []);
```

And this will ensure a re-render, since components always re-render on state change.

You can call `setRerender(!rerender)` anywhere anytime to initiate re-render.

Comment: Answer is not true. Render will only fire when the symbol is used in JSX.

Comment: @Drew which symbol?

Comment: rerender... basically `{rerender}` in the JSX block

Answer (score 0):

```
const [state, set] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
  fn();
},[state])

function fn() {
  setTimeout((), {
    set(prev => prev + 1)
  }, 3000)
}
```

The code above will re-render the `fn` function once every 3 seconds.

Comment: Extremely bad practice. You wouldn't want set a timer to refresh page based on increments; you should instead, use events (like a state change) to re-render a page. If this re-render occurred as a high level component, you'll unnecessarily re-render children components and cause major performance issues. Essentially, this solution may work, but isn't scalable for professional applications.

Comment: the code above will let you understand how  re render function works not use it in "profesional applications"