# How to rerender component after changing data in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, render, lifecycle

I creating website with authorization. And I want to show different icons on home page, if user auth or not. But componnet render earsly then data user data changing.

For authorization I use react context.

```js
export const UserProvider = ({children}) =>{
    const [user, setUser] = useState(getObjectCookie('user') === undefined ? null : getObjectCookie('user'))


    const signIn = async ({email, password}) =>{
        return await fetch('http://localhost:5000/user/add', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                email: email,
                password: password
            }),
            headers: {
                "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
            }
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(resultData => {
                console.log(resultData.message);
                const userData = resultData.createdUser
                setObjectCookie('user', {id: userData._id, email: userData.email}, {expires: new Date(2030, 1)})
                console.log('User\'s cookie set');
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error.message)
                return Promise.reject(error)
            })
    }
}
```

To check what of icon use, I check of user auth in render html

```js
<div className="d-flex flex-pow btn-header">
    <div className=" d-flex flex-column center-elements">
        <a href="/profile">
        {user !== null ?
           <>
               <img src={require("../assets/icons/icon-profile.png")} alt="Вход" className="log-in" />
               <p>Вход</p>
           </> :
           <>
               <img src={equire("../assets/icons/header-entry.png")} alt="Вход" className="log-in" />
               <p>Вход</p>
           </>
                                
        }
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Header if user none auth
[image: Header if user none auth]

Header if user auth
[image: Header if user auth]

But when I register icon not changing. I log path of action and how you can see Header render before user data is change. And I don't know how to fix this.

[image]

Function on register button

```js
 const registerUser = async (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault()
        await signIn(formData)
            .then(res => {
                console.log('Its redirect');
                navigate('/')
            })
            .catch(error => console.log('SignIN error'))
    }
```

Auth function in ReactContext

```js
const signIn = async ({email, password}) =>{
        return await fetch('http://localhost:5000/user/add', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                email: email,
                password: password
            }),
            headers: {
                "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
            }
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(resultData => {
                console.log(resultData.message);
                const userData = resultData.createdUser
                setObjectCookie('user', {id: userData._id, email: userData.email}, {expires: new Date(2030, 1)})
                console.log('User\'s cookie set');
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error.message)
                return Promise.reject(error)
            })
    }
```

I try to useState and useEffect.

```js
const [profileIcon, setProfileIcon] = useState(user !== null ? '../assets/icons/icon-profile.png' : '../assets/icons/header-entry.png')   
    const [profileLabel, setProfileLabel] = useState(user !== null ? 'Профиль' : 'Вход')   

    console.log('Header render');

    useEffect(() =>{
        if (user !== null){
            setProfileIcon('../assets/icons/icon-profile.png')
            setProfileLabel('Профиль')
        } else{
            setProfileIcon('../assets/icons/header-entry.png')
            setProfileLabel('Вход')
        }
    }, [user])

    const undottedUL = {
        "listStyleType": "none"
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to rerender component in useEffect Hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58015602/how-to-rerender-component-in-useeffect-hook)

Comment: `user` should be in the state too

Comment: @adampweb No, it does

Comment: @FlorentM. I keep user data in state of UserContext. 
`const UserContext = createContext()

export const useAuth = () => useContext(UserContext)

export const UserProvider = ({children}) =>{
    const [user, setUser] = useState(getObjectCookie('user') === undefined ? null : getObjectCookie('user'))`

Comment: Where do you call `setUser` ?

Comment: @FlorentM. Oh, yes, I'm not set user. Only set In cookie and thinking it's enough). Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Not sure it will fix the issue but you can simplify the code by removing the useEffect altogether. Replace with derived state:

```
const profileLabel = user !== null ? 'Профиль' : 'Вход';
```

Edited to show useMemo based on comments:

```
 const profile = useMemo(() => {
    if (user) {
      return {
        icon: '../assets/icons/icon-profile.png',
        label:'Профиль'
      };
    }
    return {
      icon: '../assets/icons/header-entry.png',
      label:'Вход'
    };
  }, [user]);
```

Comment: Maybe I'm not understand your idea, but user data update later than header component render.  I use this condition in html code yet, but user data is not correct, because of that I tried useEffect

Comment: By doing that `profileLabel` will be recalculated on each rerender, that is not a good way to do it. It is possible with `useMemo` though

Comment: @FlorentM. I'm bad know how work useMemo, but it calculate data between rerenders. In my situation header don't rernder, it render one time until user data is updating

Comment: From what I have read, useMemo and useCallback should only be used to avoid a performance hit from rerendering. React by design rerenders basically everything and most trivial prop rerenders have no affect on performance.


Regardless, I was just pointing out that useEffect is not the correct route and derived state would be easier (with or without useMemo). :)